# Access to props of clicked element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am newbie at programming and jQuery too.I am trying to make a dynamic photo viewer.All data for images(including url for images) is in obj prop  `response` , which value is array of an objects, which have a lot of props, but I need only `src` and `src_big`,this values is URLs.
The idea is when you click on a preview of image, it will display  a `modalDiv`, and append an `<img>`(`<img>` URL is in `src_big` prop value) to this `<div>`.

So, i already can create dynamic previews of images(`imgContainer`), using src property of each object in array, but I cant figure out how to catch a `src_big` prop of clicked element to show full size of clicked image.

Here is the code:

```
var testArray = {response:
        [{src:"1_small.jpg",
             src_big:"1.jpg"
            },
            {
             src:"2_small.jpg",
             src_big:"2.jpg"
            },
            {
             src:"3_small.jpg",
             src_big:"3.jpg"
            },
            {
             src:"4_small.jpg",
             src_big:"4.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    i= 0,
    arrContainer = $(".array-container"),
    modalDiv = $(".mod-div"),
    body = $("body"),
    imgContainer = $(".img-container"),
    arr=[];


for(i; i<testArray.response.length;++i){ \\CREATE IMG CONTAINER

    arrContainer.append($("<div class='img-container'></div>").css({"background-image":'url("' + testArray.response[i].src + '")',
            "width":"200px","height":"200px"}));

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you just want to show the big image when you click on the small image. You can do this by getting the index of the clicked div.

```
arrContainer.on('click', '.img-container', function() {
  var indx = $(this).index();
  var src_big = testArray.response[indx].src_big; // this will be your big image url
});
```

Comment: When i click on an element, it displays next image in array, not current.

Comment: You can do  `var indx = $(this).index() - 1;`, are there more images in the parent than the ones you add?